# java beginner: print two dimensional array element in a String

Tags: java, arrays, string, element

```
package arrays;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Route {

int cityindex;
int stadtwahl;
String[] cities = {"Berlin", "Hamburg", "Kiel", "Muenchen", "Stuttgart", "Dresden", "Heidelberg"};
int stadtwahlA;
int stadtwahlB;
int[][] entfernung;
int A;
int B;


public void Route() {

    entfernung = new int[A][B];
    this.A = A;
    this.B = B;
    entfernung[0][1] = entfernung [1][0] = 288;
    entfernung[0][2] = entfernung [2][0] = 355;
    entfernung[0][3] = entfernung [3][0] = 585;
    entfernung[0][4] = entfernung [4][0] = 632;
    entfernung[0][5] = entfernung [5][0] = 194;
    entfernung[0][6] = entfernung [6][0] = 628;


}

    public void einlesen() {


        System.out.println("Sie haben folgende Staedte zur Auswahl: " 
        + "\n0: " + cities[0] //Berlin
        + "\n1: " + cities[1] //Hamburg
        + "\n2: " + cities[2] //Kiel
        + "\n3: " + cities[3] //Muenchen
        + "\n4: " + cities[4] //Stuttgart
        + "\n5: " + cities[5] //Dresden
        + "\n6: " + cities[6] + "\n"); //Heidelberg

        System.out.println("Bitte waehlen Sie eine Stadt: ");
        stadtwahlA = Konsole.getInputInt();
        System.out.println("Bitte waehlen Sie ein Ziel: ");
        stadtwahlB = Konsole.getInputInt();

    }

        public void ausgabe() {
            System.out.println("Die Entfernung zwischen " + cities[stadtwahlA] + " und " + cities[stadtwahlB] + " betraegt : " );
            this.A = stadtwahlA;
            this.B = stadtwahlB;
            System.out.print(entfernung[0][1]);
            }
}
```

my idea was to print the distance (entfernung) between some cities.
so for testing reasons i just entered the distance between the city 0 (berlin) and the others. eventually i want to write

```
 System.out.print(entfernung[stadtwahlA][stadtwahlB]);
```

or at least that seemed to be the best choice for me - but for some reason, i get a nullpointerexception when running this code:

> Sie haben folgende Staedte zur Auswahl:  0: Berlin 1: Hamburg 2: Kiel
>   3: Muenchen 4: Stuttgart 5: Dresden 6: Heidelberg
>
> Bitte waehlen Sie eine Stadt:  1 Bitte waehlen Sie ein Ziel:  5 Die
>   Entfernung zwischen Hamburg und Dresden betraegt :  Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   arrays.Route.ausgabe(Route.java:70)   at
>   arrays.RouteTest.main(RouteTest.java:8)

since i am a newbie and all, i'd be very thankful for any help thats explaining me where my fault is as easy as possible ;) thanks in advance!

edit: this is my test class:

```
    package arrays;

public class RouteTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Route R1 = new Route();
        R1.einlesen();
        R1.ausgabe();


    }

}
```

Comment: Please post all your code so I can run the program. There is no main method in the code you listed.

Comment: What do you think `A` and `B` is in `entfernung = new int[A][B]; this.A = A; this.B = B;`?

Comment: @Pshemo oh, this was just a tryout, a lucky shot to see if it would make any difference...

Comment: @JoshChappelle i have edited the post with my test class

Comment: What is Konsole? The code compiles except for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is because you have void in front of what you mean to be a constructor in Route. So entfernung is never getting initialized. It's null.

Change

```
public void Route() {
```

To this

```
public Route() {
```

The next error you will hit is an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because your constructor is declaring a 0 by 0 size array and then you are trying to reference the [0][1] element of that array which doesn't exist. That's because you haven't initialized the A and B variables. I'll leave that to you as an excercise.

Comment: nice, thanks. and you were right, my next problem IS an indexoutofbounds... ill try to figure it out for now and maybe come back later. thanks so far!

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if that solved your problem.

Comment: will the tread then be closed? what i have further questions? to be honest, dont know how to solve the new arrayindexoutofboundsexception... ive been coding the whole day and i am totally tired, but i have to get this stuff done by tomorrow.

Comment: No it won't be closed. It just marks the answer as accepted and gives me credit for the answer. If you have another question I suggest creating a new thread for that.

Comment: for a good reason i'm not allowed to post another question within 90 minutes - can you give me a hint in this thread?

Comment: Change entfernung = new int[A][B]; to this entfernung = new int[7][7];

Comment: man, i had that idea myself and changed it to 6/6 ... sometimes you cant see the most obvious things. thanks so much mate!